# How to send message using xmpppy to a jabber client?

Tags: python, xmpp, xmpppy

I've to send xmpp based chat client (hipchat) and I'm using [xmpp.py](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose. For now, I'm trying to send message from shell. Following are the statements that I'm executing from the shell:

```
>>> import xmpp
>>> jid = xmpp.protocol.JID('99999_9999@chat.hipchat.com')
>>> cl=xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(),debug=[])
>>> cl.connect()
'tls'
>>> cl.auth(jid.getNode(),'password')
'sasl'
>>> cl.send(xmpp.protocol.Message('99999_9999@chat.hipchat.com','hey!'))
'3'
```

I'm using the same jabber id for authentication and as a receiver. I'm also online in chat room but I don't get any message. What's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the `typ` parameter. Adding it with value `chat` solved the problem:

```
cl.send(xmpp.protocol.Message('99999_9999@chat.hipchat.com','hey!', typ='chat'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some older XMPP servers need an initial presence state.
The state is sent using the following call before the `cl.send`:

```
cl.SendInitPresence(requestRoster=0)
```

See also the xsend example from xmpppy home page:
http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/examples/xsend.py